# Bitcoind estimatesmartfee

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, json-rpc, fee-estimation

I am trying to get transaction fee for sending all btc to another account.
I use estimatesmartfee to get tx fee, I have total btc amount of 0.0195btc, so I pass 0.0195, but I get `JSON integer out of range (code -1)`

Answer (score 2):

`estimatesmartfee` expects the number of blocks you want the tx confirmed in as the parameter, not the amount of BTC you are sending.

Try `estimatesmartfee 5` to get an estimate for confirmation in the next 5 blocks, for instance.

Comment: thanks, but I followed your command but it still throws some error `{
  "errors": [
    "Insufficient data or no feerate found"
  ],
  "blocks": 1
}`

Comment: Your node has not seen enough blocks to make an estimate yet, or does not have the feerate configured correctly